# Find directories in a given range size

Tags: linux, bash, find, du

I am trying to find directories in a given size but it doesn't display. I am running the code on the desired directory and I run

```
du -h --maxdepth 1
```

To make sure that the directories have the sizes I want to find. But when I run:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -size +5M -size -3M
```

it doesn't display anything.

Comment: `max-depth` ?..

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607475/linux-find-command-how-to-find-directories-by-size

Comment: Do you want 3 to 5MiB dirs or something different? My understanding is that a range is numX to numY

Comment: I think you are confusing here the _size of an directory_ with _the sum of all files in the directory_. The latter is what `du` reports.

Answer (score 0):

You're supplying mutually exclusive requirements, so nothing can match.

Use an *or*.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( -size +5M -o -size -3M \)
```

If that gets no hits, maybe none of the directories at `-maxdepth 1` fit the conditions. Try removing that.

```
find . -type d \( -size +5M -o -size -3M \)
```

I think you're not going to `find` a lot of directories >5M, though. `find` isn't reporting the same data as `du`. It's a lot like the `ls` vs `du` questioned asked [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371238/what-is-the-difference-between-file-size-in-ls-l-and-du-sh).

maybe what you want is something more like one of these.

```
du -b | awk '$1<3000000||$1>5000000' # or
du -b | awk '$1<3145728||$1>5242880' | sort -n
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do to find dirs in range `3 to 5MiB`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec bash -c '
        for d; do
            s=$(du -s -B M "$d" | sed -E "s/^([0-9]+).*/\1/")
            ((s>=3 && s<=5)) && echo "$d ${s}MiB"
        done
    ' bash {} +
```

[image: warning] `find`'s `-size` is meant for files, not for directory.

---

Or as far as you only treat only current directory:

```
du -sb */ | awk '$1>3000000 && $1<5000000'
```

Answer (score 0):

`find -type d -size` does not work as you apparently think. It considers the size of the directories that `ls -l` shows, not the total size of the content of the directories (the files they contain). If you are interested in the total size of the content you must use `du` in your `find` command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -execdir bash -c \
  's=($(du -sb "$1")); (( 3145728 <= s[0] && s[0] <= 5242880 ))' _ {} \; -print
```

Note that `-size +5M -size -3M` means "*strictly more than 5M **and** strictly less than 3M*" which, even if the `find` directory sizes were what you think, would obviously return nothing. Note also that, due to the rounding, `-size -3M` means less or equal than `2M` and `-size +5M` means more or equal `6M`.